# On a deterministic primes search problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, prime-gaps

I feel the following problem might be resolved already. But I could not find any related answers.

> If $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_t$ are primes where $2\leq t=o(\log n)$ is there a prime within $$\prod_{i=1}^tp_i\pm O(\log^k(\prod_{i=1}^tp_i))$$ at a $k$ in $[1,2)$ and if not is $k=2$ possible at least?

> If we assume Cramer $k=2$ is possible. Does the above at $k\leq2$ imply Cramer?

Such a result would help in deterministic search of primes which is an open problem.

Perhaps $O(n)$ or $O\Big(\frac{n}{\log n}\Big)$ number of distinct small primes of $O(\log n + \log\log n)$ bits each qualifies as sufficient information to find $\Omega(\log n)$ or $\Omega(1)$ distinct primes respectively of $\Omega(n)$ bits each in $poly(n)$ time if a result of this sort can unconditionally exist.

Comment: I doubt any results are known which would be better than for general numbers. In particular the Cramer heuristic suggests it will be false for all $k<2$, and $k=2$ is just as hopeless as Cramer.

Comment: I'm not claiming they are equivalent, just that they appear to be comparable in difficulty

Comment: Suggests is not a proof though in the particular situation. Is it really following through Cramer heuristic where $t=1$ which I have ignored?